# toString not printing actual array values within a JApplet

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

Here's my applet.

[JApplet](https://pastebin.com/JMrjZLm3)

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    Font font = new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 12);
    g.setFont(font);

    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillRect(0, 105, 500, 500);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g.drawString("hello", 120, 300);

    for(int c = 0; c < 1;){

        for(int b = 250; c < 9; b = b + 10){
            g.drawString(roster[c].toString(), 10, b);
            c++;
        }

    }
    g.drawString(roster[0].toString(), 0, 250);



}
    public Student[] setup(){
    count = 10;
    roster = new Student[count];
    int x = 0; int e = 0;
    int[] gtest = new int[5];

    for(e = 0; e < 5; e++){
         gtest[e] = 0;
    }


    for(x = 0; x < 31; x++){
      roster[x] = new Student("", 0, gtest);
    }

    int[] help = new int[5];
    help[0] = 84; help[1] = 85; help[2] = 86; help[3] = 87; help[4] = 88;

    roster[0] = new Student("Pocket, beam", 2017, new int[] {84, 85, 84, 87, 88, 88});
    roster[1] = new Student("Zuckerberg, Marcus", 2017, help);
    roster[2] = new Student("Timelapse, Random", 2013, help);
    roster[3] = new Student("Timelapse, Random2", 2013, help);
    roster[4] = new Student("Timelapse, Random3", 2016, help);
    roster[5] = new Student("god, not", 2016, help);
    roster[6] = new Student("Webster, Jacques", 2016, help);
    roster[7] = new Student("East, Kanayo", 2016, help);
    roster[8] = new Student("Blue, Canoe", 2017, help);
    roster[9] = new Student("West, East", 2017, help);

    return(roster);

}
```

I pasted the specific code as well, the `.toString` is in the Graphics method.

Here's my `toString` method within the constructor class.

```
public String toString(){
    DecimalFormat tens = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    String ans = String.format("%-20s%-8s %-5s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-10s", name, year,
    grades[0], grades[1], grades[2], grades[3], grades[4], tens.format(gpa));
    return(ans);

}
```

So I believe the issue is with how I'm calling `.toString`, my googling has shown that I'm supposed to use `java.util.Arrays`? I've tried that and I can't figure out what's wrong. I know its a simple syntax error but I can't pick out what it is.

What happens is that the roster numbers are printed onto the **applet**, but all the values are 0.00 or 0 or whatever 0 in their respective formats.

Also `repaint()` is called in my `actionperformed` method

Comment: Did you try to call repaint()?

Comment: I did, it's in my actionperformed method

Comment: For one thing, your loop from x = 0 to 31 is causing an array index out of bounds since the roster array is only size 10.

Comment: Besides that, your toString is working just fine! The problem is that they are getting painted outside of the bounds of your applet. Try resizing your applet taller (after getting rid of the x=0-31 for loop), and you will see  your text printed as you probably are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

In the `setup` function, GET RID OF THIS:

```
for(x = 0; x < 31; x++){
  roster[x] = new Student("", 0, gtest);
}
```

It is causing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because `roster` only has 10 elements.

Then, change your text painting look to look like this:

```
// Ger rid of the outer loop on c
// for (int c = 0; c < 1) {
// Change your initial b value from 250 to 115. 250 is too low for your window
for(int b = 115, c = 0; c < 9; b = b + 10){
    g.drawString(roster[c].toString(), 10, b);
    c++;
}
// }
```